# Can I use javascript/jquery to submit a non-local form in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, jquery

I am building a page at `http://www.localurl.com`.

I want to submit a POST form that is on `http://www.url.com/form_step_1.html` to `http://www.url.com/form_step_2.html` and display `http://www.url.com/form_step_2.html` in an iframe.

Is this possible to do with JavaScript/jQuery or does browser security prohibit this?  Is there anyway it can be done with ajax?

## In addition to the selected answer, I found [this blog post](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) extraordinarily informative on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute Javascript on a different domain that you do not have access to.

If you do have access then use:

```
document.domain = 'example.com'
```

on both pages. You can then submit a form within the iFrame with this:

```
window.top.myiframename.document.myformname.submit();
```

or

```
window.myiframename.document.myformname.submit();
```

NOTE: This probably won't work in IE8.

Alternatively, you could create your own page on your domain using php:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://www.url.com");
?>
```

Open this page (which is on your local host) in your iframe and use:

```
    window.top.myiframename.document.myformname.submit();
```

or
    window.myiframename.document.myformname.submit();

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you want, but you can submit a form with its `target` set to the name of the iframe.

On `foo.com`:

```
<form action="http://bar.com/action" method="POST" target="baz">
  ...
</form>

<iframe name="baz" ...></iframe>
```